# Cómo puedo crear un programa que solicite una contraseña que inicie con un número y después pida volver a ingresar la contraseña con 3 intentos

Tags: python, validación, contraseña

me pidieron crear un código con las siguientes características:
● Que solicite una contraseña que inicie con un número.
● Que pida ingresar nuevamente la contraseña y verificar que coincida con la primera ingresada.
● Si se cometen tres errores al ingresar la contraseña, que despliegue un mensaje de aviso y cierre el programa.

Esto es lo que llevo:

```
numeroDeIntentos = 3
for i in range(numeroDeIntentos):
    contraseña = input("Ingrese de favor su contraseña: ")
    if contraseña == 'contraseña':
        print("Gracias, bienvenido")
        break
    print('Incorrecto.  %d intentos restantes' % (numeroDeIntentos-i-1))
```

Comment: Y ¿Cuál es la pregunta o el problema? ¿Qué te impide seguir adelante?

Comment: La pregunta es como agrego que el programa pida iniciar con un numero y que pida ingresar cualquier contraseña que el usuario ingrese, no el que yo ponga en el código. A eso me refiero...

Comment: Podrías empezar revisando si el `string` inicia con un dígito, ya sea utilizando `startswith` o el índice `0` del `string` en conjunto con `isdigit()`

Comment: Los tres reintentos son a la hora de crear una contraseña válida (que empiece por dígito)? O son a la hora de verificar que la contraseña válida ya introducida coincide con la que luego se le pide repetir? O ambas cosas? Y no queda claro en la especificación qué hacer si la contraseña que se le pide repetir no coincide con la primera ingresada ¿hay que pedirle otra vez la primera ingresada, o esa ya no se pide de nuevo?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Es cosa de reordenar un poco el código.

Primero, la validación es tan simple como preguntar si el primer caracter `isdigit()`. Si pasa esa validación, pedidos la confirmación de la contraseña, y si ambas coinciden, terminamos.

Lo segundo es agregar una variable `valida` que registre el éxito del proceso, para saber si terminó con una contraseña bien ingresada o no.

```
numeroDeIntentos = 3
valida = False
for i in range(numeroDeIntentos):
    contraseña1 = input("Ingrese de favor su contraseña: ")
    if contraseña1[0].isdigit():
        contraseña2 = input("Repita su contraseña: ")
        if contraseña1 == contraseña2:
            print("Gracias, bienvenido")
            valida = True
            break
        else:
            print('Incorrecto.  %d intentos restantes' % (numeroDeIntentos-i-1))
```

produce:

```
Ingrese de favor su contraseña: abc
Ingrese de favor su contraseña: 1abc
Repita su contraseña: 1abc
Gracias, bienvenido

Process finished with exit code 0
```